# Embed Qt application into external window

Tags: qt, x11

I have Qt application that I want to render onto a window provided by external application in Linux / X environment.

I know it is possible to start some applications and tell them to project themselves on one of my widgets: I get internally `QWidget::winId()` and start erxternal application with this as a parameter. I want to do reverse: start my Qt application with xid provided from elsewhere. I can't find how to do this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out (explanation in comments):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // create QWindow
    int hwnd = 35651603; // provided from other app, should be dynamic
    QWindow *nativeWindow = QWindow::fromWinId(hwnd);

    // Prepare something to show
    MainWindow w;
    
    // move displayed widget to desired location
    w.windowHandle()->setParent(nativeWindow);
    w.move(0, 0);

    // actually display. Must be done last
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/tests/manual/xembed/qt-client-raster/main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStringList args = app.arguments();

    WId winId = 0;
    if (args.count() > 1) {
        bool ok;
        winId = args[1].toUInt(&ok);
        Q_ASSERT(ok);
    }

    RasterWindow window;

    QWindow *foreign = QWindow::fromWinId(winId);
    Q_ASSERT(foreign != 0);

    window.setParent(foreign);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```